# What sorts of unlockables are there and how do I get them?

Tags: crawl

I've unlocked a new deity so far, as well as a few weapons and a spell. What other things can I unlock? How do I unlock things? Is it just random when I finish a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also unlock new evolutions for existing creatures. (You may have noticed the locked evolution symbols in the monster evolution screens between floors)

To unlock something, simply finish a match.

Comment: In addition to this, I would add that the "something" encompasses, so far, weapons, spells, traps, and monsters. There are plenty of weapon and spell types to be unlocked and it seems as though there are a few traps and maybe 3-4 monsters.